# How to use SET command in MySQL instead of SELECT statement for storing the value in STORED PROCEDURE (Version : 6.0.11-alpha-community)

Tags: mysql

I want to store the one table data row 'Id' into variable and I used the SELECT statement for that in stored procedure.

EX:

```
  SET @IRid := 1;
  SET @iCID := 0;

 SELECT @iCID := Id FROM tbl_custidData WHERE RID = @IRid;
```

The Id value is storing successfully into the @iCID

Here My question is, can I use SET command instead of SELECT statement to store the one table id value into variable ?

I tried this way but not working ( directly assigning the value into variable )

```
  SET @IRid := 1;
  SET @iCID := 0;

 SET @iCID := Id FROM tbl_custidData WHERE RID = @IRid;
```

And also I tried like this (declaring the variable and assigning the value) :

```
        DECLARE IRid,iCID INT;
        SET IRid =1;
        SET iCID = 0;

 SET iCID := Id FROM tbl_custidData WHERE RID = IRid;
```

The above two ways are not working

Is there any possibility in MySQL for the use of SET command to assign the table id value, like how I used the SELECT statement.

I'm new to MYSQL .

Give me your best solution for my further good steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want SET and only it then

```
SET @iCID := (SELECT Id FROM tbl_custidData WHERE RID = @IRid LIMIT 1);
```

But `SELECT Id INTO @iCID FROM tbl_custidData WHERE RID = @IRid LIMIT 1` may be more useful...

Comment: Thanks @Akina It's working fine for me